Why isn't TREE(2) = 5?
I'm trying to comprehend $\operatorname{TREE
(3)}$ but i can't even comprehend $\operatorname{TREE(2)}$
So there are $2$ rules:

The $n$-th tree should contain at most $n$ nodes.
All the previous $(n - 1)$ trees should not be inf-embeddable within the nth tree.

let's have red nodes $(R)$ and black nodes $(B)$

$R$
$B$-$B$
$B$
$R$-$R$ .. all previous trees are not contained in this because $2$nd and $3$rd are black while this is all red
$R$-$B$ .. there was no $R$-$B$ combination yet so how is this contained in all previous trees?


R-R and R-B contain R.

I think at some point you switched from asking "are previous trees embeddable in this one?" to "is this tree embeddable in previous trees?" and the second question is the wrong question to ask.

thank you, i think i did not understand it after all. yes, none of the previous trees must not be contained in the last one. silly me
